# How to get $refs in Vue 3 nested app (Vue app in other Vue app)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to get marriage of **Vue 3** and my **MVC** app:

I have main container on `_Layout.cshtml` with Vue app initialized:

```
<div id="app">
    <el-container>
        <el-main>
            @RenderBody()
        </el-main>
    </el-container>
</div>

var appHome = createApp(config);
appHome.mount("#app");
```

Then in @RenderBody() I get page with another Vue app (another .cshtml page + another .js controller):

```
<div id="appInner" ref="appInner">
    ...
</div>

var appInner = createApp(config);
appInner.mount("#appInner");
```

After that I can get information about appInner in $refs of top app:

```
//it is from config of my main container app (appHome)
mounted() {
    console.log('this.$refs AppHome', this.$refs); //here I can see ref to appInner
},
```

The problem is that I have to get ref for appInner in $refs for my appInner instance, so I need to see in:

```
//it is from config of my inner app (appInner)
mounted() {
    console.log('this.$refs AppInner', this.$refs); //here I can not see ref to appInner but I need that
},
```

Is that possible to achieve this goal in some way?

Comment: You can't have a ref on the vue container, but you can use window.appInner to get it, since you used `var`

Comment: Yes, I can see appInner object, but I can't invoke method on refs element. I get <el-table ref="table"> and I want to invoke method table.doLayout() but I can see only DOM element of "table" and doLayout() method is missing.

Comment: well you won't be able to call a method from outside the vue app, you need to find another way like broadcasting a message